# CefSharp error: "Browser not yet initialized" when execute "ExecuteScriptAsync" or "EvaluateScriptAsync"

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm trying to execute javascript using CeSharp.
In the end I got an error:
Browser is not yet initialized. Use the IsBrowserInitializedChanged event and check the IsBrowserInitialized property to determine when the browser has been intialized.

When I used: "ExecuteScriptAsync" method like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

namespace CefSharp
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Start the browser after initialize global component
            InitializeChromium();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("alert('Adam')");
        }

        public void InitializeChromium()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings
            {
                CachePath = "cache"
            };
            // Initialize cef with the provided settings
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            // Create a browser component
            chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://localhost/Test/index.html");

            // Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.
            this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
            chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }
    }    
}
```

or when I used "EvaluateScriptAsync"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

namespace CefSharp
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public ChromiumWebBrowser chromeBrowser;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Start the browser after initialize global component
            InitializeChromium();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var task = chromeBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync("alert('Adam')");

            task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if (!t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    var response = t.Result;
                    var EvaluateJavaScriptResult = response.Success ? (response.Result ?? "null") : response.Message;
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }

        public void InitializeChromium()
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            // Initialize cef with the provided settings
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
            // Create a browser component
            chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://localhost/Test/index.html");

            // Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.
            this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
            chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }
    }    
}
```

Does anyone know how to handle it ?

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript

Comment: Hi @amaitland Is there a way to get the document (like we can on the default webbrowser controler) ? and also is it possible to check the readyState = "completed" of the browser ?

Comment: You can only access the DOM through JavaScript. What do you need to know the readystate for exactly?

Comment: If you execute JavaScript in LoadingStateChanged the document should be ready

Comment: Hi @amaitland , I would like to invoke a javascript function from a method in my C# code. Is there a way to execute it from a method without subscribe to an event ?

Comment: Hard to say, not really enough to go on. You need to make sure the browser has sufficiently loaded before you can execute `JavaScript`. read over the link I provided again maybe?

Comment: @amaitland thank you! I have successfully implemented it finally. I have one last issue - once the browser loaded, it take the focus and the application is no longer listen a keyboard key press.. Is there a way to prevent cefSharp from taking the focus ?

Comment: Set the focus to another control?

Comment: You can use `IKeyboardHandler` to handle key presses when the browser does have focus.

Comment: @amaitland, the 2nd is that I have a user control with list of item, and then above there is the browser. When I select an item (by the arrow keys) it get load in the browser below. Once the item get load by calling the load method. the focus from the list got lost - when I click the arrows the don;t function anymore. I couldn't handle it with with what you've wrote. Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: @amaitland why not make your comment into an answer? :)